# Ask password in window mode after sudo or other command line operations?

Tags: x11, sudo, password, authentication, gui

Was seen in movies, that after command line operations, the password was asked in separate GUI window.

[image]

From my (small) experience, password, required from command line, was always asked in command line too. Common example: a `sudo` program.

Today I met another example. I was doing first run pf `PyCharm` and was doing this from `Putty` command line, having `DISPLAY` pointing to my client computer, running `XMing`. So all windows were shown on `Windows`. But some authentication was still asked in command line.

So, the question is: is it possible to force all authentication requests be shown in windows mode, like in `Matrix`?

Answer (score 1):

On a technical level, there's no way to tell that the string a program is requesting will be used as a password.

On the other hand, there are [kdesu](https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/kdesu) and [gksudo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo) which are, to a first approximation, "`sudo` but with a popup window for the password".